# I have a two-bins trashcan drawer with blum tracks (568R452-09). What do I need to add a blum servo drive to it?

Tags: drawers

I have a two-bins trashcan drawer with blum tracks (marking on the tracks says 568R452-09). What do I need to add a blum servo drive to it? (in addition to the servo drive motor, obviously).

Specifically, do I need special soft-closers to work with the servo drive?

servo drive model #: Z10NA30UGUS

Comment: To be fair, their [installation instructions](https://www.blum.com/file/servodrive_ma_dok_bus?country=us&language=en) (PDF) don't seem to say anything at all about soft closers. Have you contacted Blum to ask them?

Comment: @FreeMan, they sent me back a catalog and suggested reaching out to local retailers.

Comment: I know nothing but very curious ... why would a servo drive need a soft closer?  Why wouldn't it just close the drawer softly, or not softly, or however the programmer wants it to close?

Comment: That's not a particularly helpful response. Have you reached out to a local retailer to see what they say? (Keep in mind their goal is selling stuff, so if they insist you need them, get 2 or 3 more opinions, just to be sure.)

Comment: @jay613. That's what I was expecting, but the drawer just bounces back (a few mm) when I close it, it doesn't feel like servo drive provides any "slowing down" on closing.

Comment: You should complain.  I bet that motor costs a bundle.  And calling it a "servo drive", while it may be technically accurate, implies precise control of movement and acceleration because that's the whole point of servo motors.  But it has to be programmed into the controller and apparently that hasn't been done.  If the servo is dumb it will actually fight with the soft closer, trying to push it instead of letting the closer do the work.

Answer (score 1):

I installed servo drive uno by blum but my kitchen fabricator supplied the parts which included the tracks and bins.  The track does the soft close.  The servo only handles the opening when you hip check the door front.

Comment: Could you provide a model of the tracks used? can you verify there is no soft closer installed on the tracks? My problem is without a soft closer the drawer bounces back when I close it (not by servo, but just the impact at the end of the tracks). I don't think servo motor provides any soft-closing. I probably did it wrong.

Comment: The tracks say Blum Tandembox 65kg blumotion